# Check for number of values in a key using Multimap

Tags: java, guava

I'd like to check if there are a certain number of values for a given key within a Multimap. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can perform a `get(key)` that will return a collection, over that collection you invoke `size()` to find out how many elements are on the `Multimap` associated with the given key.

From the [documentation](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html):

> Collection    get(K key) Returns a collection view of all values
>   associated with a key.

Answer (score 4):

Either `multimap.get(key).size()` or `multimap.keys().count(key)` will work. If it matters, the first will probably "waste" an object instance and the second will probably not.